# Live Server for VS Code showing 'Hello World' page

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have scoured google/stack/git for anything related to this problem and can't find anything even close to the problem I'm having. Which makes me think it's something really simple and boneheaded that I'm missing, or it's a rare problem.

I'm trying to view my html files using the Live Server extension while I'm working on them.  When I click on the html file to 'open in live server', it opens to a page showing 'Hello World', NOT the html file I'm working on. I have no clue where this page is even coming from but assume it's some kind of boilerplate. I've included screen shots.. Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.
[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg5Wa.png)

Comment: Can you tell you what do you have in your folder ? List the files present in `JS-BASICS` folder.

Comment: The open html was coming out of JS-DOM folder which has 2 other boilerplate index.html files & a practice dom-nodes.html file. Now the different folder you’re mentioning JS-BASICS has an index.html file and an index.js file . These two I downloaded for a course on working with js.

Comment: I just deleted that open “JS-BASICS” folder .. and problem is solved. I am curious as to why that folder took precedent over live server / vs code though . Guess that will come with practice. Sorry for the dumb question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I saw your screenshot. It happens when your index.html file is in the root folder.

Make a new folder under root named public or anything.
put your index.html file inside the folder.

Now Open with Live Server. You will see your page.